questionnaire with no page break between question and answer's first 2~3 lines
here is a question - answer like document where at the end of the first page there is a page break right after a question.
I want that page breaking is not allowed between the question and the beginning of its answer. So if the answer is 10 lines long, a page break after at the 3rd or 4th line should be allowed.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,blindtext,lipsum}

\newenvironment{questionnaire}
  {\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]\bfseries}
  {\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{myanswer}{\par\normalfont}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{questionnaire}

\item some lipsum
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{myanswer}

\item some more \dots
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[3-4]
  \end{myanswer}

\item again
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[2][1-4]
  \end{myanswer}

\item again
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[5]
  \end{myanswer}

\item again
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[6]
  \end{myanswer}
\end{questionnaire}
\end{document}




Use \nopagebreak at the point you want no page break:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,blindtext,lipsum}

\newenvironment{questionnaire}
  {\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]\bfseries}
  {\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{myanswer}{\par\nopagebreak\normalfont}{\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{questionnaire}

\item some lipsum
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{myanswer}

\item some more \dots
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[3-4]
  \end{myanswer}

\item again
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[2][1-4]
  \end{myanswer}

\item again
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[5]
  \end{myanswer}

\item again
  \begin{myanswer}
    \lipsum[6]
  \end{myanswer}
\end{questionnaire}
\end{document}


It seems it jumps as soon as there is no space enough for two lines for the paragraph. It's fine for me
